# Invalid Intent Vocabulary for SiriKit

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, sirikit

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XXXX App". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

> **Invalid Intent Vocabulary** - The AppIntentVocabulary.plist file in the /Payload/XXXX.app/fr.lproj folder is **formatted incorrectly**.
>   Unable to convert file at
>   [/Volumes/data01/app_data/dstr/MZContentSchedulerContentDigester-pv48p00ce-swpr062.cse.apple.com-15000-47006200/MZWorkQueueMuncher_.0/2GRUFF7JP7EVPWQ7Q6PIFFMPS6FDUM/nfqffdfduqqjxztahghvc/zkxfsffdfdfexjrwfqkgo/Payload/XXXX.app/fr.lproj/AppIntentVocabulary.plist]
>   to NSDictionary

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Here is the file at this path

[image]